# Having Issues Locating my Data Partiton in WINE

Tags: wine

I am trying to manually boot a program from terminal into wine.  The problem is that I have a separate Data Partition.  Would the Drives used by my Windows boot part be the same under wine?  If not, how can I find out what my drive letter is?

Comment: Your wine config is in your home area.

Comment: I cant see it is the problem

Comment: You config folder is usually hidden. If in Nautilus, the shortcut is Ctrl + H

Comment: *Always hidden, the path is `.wine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the wine HDD:

~/.wine/drive_c

for example, to run Evernote:

```
wine /home/tim/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Evernote/Evernote/Evernote.exe
```

Note the `\` before the spaces and brackets.

The reason you can't see the folder is because it has a `.` before it, so it is hidden. In nautilus, to do that you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: OK so now the drive I need is a broken link.  What next?

Comment: What do you mean by a broken link?

Comment: My C drive is just that, it doesnt point to my data drive.

Comment: So you have an external hdd, and you want the folder `drive_c` to be a symbolic link to a folder on it?

Comment: no no.  Let me explain better.  I have 3 primary partitions.  I have C D and Z.  C is my windows part that is also doubled as the wine one exclusively.  My D is where everything else is.  Z is Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh no, wine doesn't link to that. Wine is separate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18743/discussion-between-virusboy-and-tim).